# cordova 3.0 / Android - input type="date" value is not set via DatePicker

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker

I'm using cordova 3.0 to build an Android APP. However, I'm trying to use

```
<input type="date"/>
```

The date picker pops out without problems, but when I set the date, the input value is empty, even when I try to alert() it via JS, it returns an empty value.

This is my logCat in case that helps:

> 03-05 11:51:39.689: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(31421): blockWebkitDraw
>
> 03-05 11:51:39.689: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(31421): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
>
> 03-05 11:51:39.989: D/webview(31421): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
>
> 03-05 11:51:40.039: D/AbsListView(31421): Get MotionRecognitionManager
>
> 03-05 11:51:40.109: D/AbsListView(31421): unregisterIRListener() is called
>
> 03-05 11:51:40.199: D/AbsListView(31421): unregisterIRListener() is called
>
> 03-05 11:51:44.529: D/AbsListView(31421): onDetachedFromWindow
>
> 03-05 11:51:44.529: D/AbsListView(31421): unregisterIRListener() is called
>
> 03-05 11:51:44.539: E/ViewRootImpl(31421): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

**NOTE**

When I open it on my emulator: it works just fine, but when I'm testing on my actual device: **Galaxy Note 3**, that's when the error occurs.

*Emulator* Android 4.4

*Device* Android 4.3

**UPDATE**

I tried on 4.3 emulator AVD, and it worked successfully. Then I tried on another galaxy Note 2 and it ***didn't*** work. =S

Any body has any idea??